# Exclude all symbolic link folders from OneDrive sync

Tags: symbolic-link, onedrive

I work on many projects that are saved on my local OneDrive folder that are then synced using OneDrive to the cloud. In each project, I use symbolic links (aka symlinks) to link to data stored on secured network drives (outside of OneDrive). I do *not* want these linked folders to backup on OneDrive sync. This is easy enough to do individually, but is there a way to exclude *all* symlinked folders from OneDrive sync? Or is it possible to omit all folders called `"secure_data"`, for example, across all of OneDrive?

Thank you,
Daniel

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Nope and nope. Sorry. Not with the Micro$oft client.  https://superuser.com/questions/1264512/how-to-exclude-node-modules-directory-from-onedrive-synchronization

Comment: Ugh, thank you @Gantendo

Answer (score 1):

You can create a **Power Automate** task.

Click on the ellipsis button besides your folder in the on-line version of One-Drive and choose Automate

[image: Power automate]